# Value cannot be null (Parameter 'connectionString') .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

I use .Net 6 and when I want to run my first migration, I get this error:

> Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')

My `appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=Solardb;integrated security=SSPI"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },

  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

And this is my `Configuration` method in `program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<SolarDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionStrings")));
```

Comment: The connection string you're trying to get is called "DefaultConnection", not "ConnectionsStrings".

Comment: You seem to use C#. That language is very different from C.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to get the whole section. GetConnectionString does it already. You just need to put the name of connection string

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<SolarDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Answer (score 0):

MY  `appsettings.json`

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaulConnection": "Data source=skinet.db"}
```

I used a much simpler structure while solving the problem. `startup.cs` :

```
services.AddDbContext<StoreContext>(x => 
x.UseSqlite(_config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Writing the following instead of the above may solve the problem.

```
services.AddDbContext<StoreContext>(x =>
x.UseSqlite(("DefaultConnection")));
```